# How to get GRUB options selection on startup?

Tags: boot, grub2, gnome, configuration

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and in the past at random seemingly there was a period in which when starting up my computer I would get the GRUB options which would allow me to choose between launching `Ubuntu`, `Advanced options for Ubuntu`, `System options`, etc...

Now however I just get a strangish gray screen with a border which is darker than the middle and then verbose console output, is there any way to force this options selection at startup? Because if I ever need to access it seemingly only causing my machine to have a cold shutdown during startup will do it which is not ideal...

Comment: have you tried to press escape key ??

Comment: @MohamedSlama: I have, I have tried actually pressing a variate of keys, but non of them seem to have any affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force it to come up every time, you need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` for example with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

comment out the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` so it looks like

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

or if you do not have that line, comment out `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

and make sure `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is set to something above 0 and enough seconds for you to do something when you get to the screen, for example

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Save & exit.

After changing this file, you have to run this command to make changes effective:

```
sudo update-grub
```

(I figured this out by reading the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) but [this popular answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/527764) also explains it)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a PC selecting `F12` during bootup will take you to the boot options section. If you go to boot-order, or something like that, and push the GRUB boot manager to the highest priority. It should boot to GRUB first after that. If you're running a Mac, it could be the same, but I've never used OSX so I don't actually know.